# How to capture matching count value in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array `x` which can have following values:

```
0: {status: "completed", count: 2}
1: {status: "pending", count: 3}
```

Now, if status is matching to `pending` then I want to capture the corresponding the `count` value.

I have written the following code:

```
if (x?.length) {
PendingCount = x[1].count;
completedCount = x[0].count;
}
```

This is not always giving the desired output because it is not necessary that `pending` status will always be at the `x[0]`

Comment: Does x have to be an array? Could your statii in the array be duplicated? If not, I'd use an Object instead, with the statii as keys. `x = {completed:{count:2},pending:{count:3}};` then call `x[status].count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Array.prototype.find to find the item with pending status and then take its count property, like so:

```
const { count } = x.find(({ status } = {}) => status === 'pending') || {}:
```

That will give you the count if a pending status exists, or undefined if one does not. I've used [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [defaulting](https://dev.to/samanthaming/3-ways-to-set-default-value-in-javascript-2253) syntax here, take a look at the articles I've linked if you're unfamiliar with them.

Answer (score 2):

If it's guaranteed that there will only be 1 element with "pending" `status`, then it seems appropriate to use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the element based on the value of its `status` property:

```js
const pendingCount = [{
  status: "completed",
  count: 2
}, {
  status: "pending",
  count: 3
}].find(el => el.status === "pending").count;

console.dir(`pending count = ${pendingCount}`);
```

If there are multiple "pending" items in the array and you need to get the sum of all, it would probably make most sense to use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (to remove all non "pending" items) and then [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the `filter` result to add the `count`s.

```js
const pendingSum = [{
    status: "completed",
    count: 2
  }, {
    status: "pending",
    count: 3
  }, {
    status: "pending",
    count: 5
  }, {
    status: "pending",
    count: 5
  }]
  .filter(el => el.status === "pending")
  .reduce((sum, el) => sum += el.count, 0);

console.dir(`sum of pending items count = ${pendingSum}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use filter, will find all elements that have pending status

```
const data = [{
    status: "completed",
    count: 2
  },
  {
    status: "pending",
    count: 3
  }
];

const pending = data.filter(s => s.status === "pending");
console.log(pending.length ? "got pending" : "no pending")
console.log(pending.map(i=>i.count))
```

Comment: `filter()` will return an array. You need to refer the object by the array index like `pending[0].length`.

Comment: that's the whole point, what if there is more then one item with status pending in array

Answer (score 1):

```
const array = [
  {status: "completed", count: 2},
  {status: "pending", count: 3}
];

const pending = array.find(s => s.status === "pending");
if (pending) {
   // Do whatever you want.
}
```